# How can we add child table dynamically in frappe (ERPNEXT)

Tags: python, erpnext, frappe

I want to add child tables dynamically depending on records in another doctype.

Comment: Please Post Question in detail

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several method to add child in parent doc:

#### Method 1:

`

```
import frappe
parent = frappe.get_doc('Sales Order', 'SO-00002')
child = frappe.new_doc("Sales Order Item")
child.update({
    'company': 'company_name',
    'item_code': 'item_code',
    'item_name': 'item_name',
    'field': 'field_value'
    'parent': parent.name,
    'parenttype': 'Sales Order',
    'parentfield': 'items'
})
parent.items.append(child)
```

#### Method 2:

```
import frappe

parent = frappe.get_doc('Sales Order', 'SO-00002')
child = frappe._dict({
     'company': 'company_name',
    'item_code': 'item_code',
    'item_name': 'item_name',
    'field': 'field_value'
})
parent.items.append(child)
```

`

Answer (score 5):

@Sajid liaz,

You can add the row in the child table using the append method

e.g.

```
doc = frappe.get_doc('Sales Order', 'SO-00002')
doc.append('items', {
    'company': 'company_name',
    'item_code': 'item_code',
    'item_name': 'item_name',
    'field': 'field_value'
})
doc.save()
```

where `items` is the child table's fieldname.

Comment: I want to add child tables dynamically not the data. for example if appraisal template has a child table with three rows then in appraisal it should generate three tables dynamically

Comment: @Sajid Ijaz

You can not add the fields runtime, instead, add the HTML field and render the html table with the data

Answer (score 2):

This is possible since DocTypes are treated as data in Frappe Framework.
However, dynamic fields added at runtime must be added as Custom Fields.

```py
from frappe.custom.doctype.custom_field.custom_field import create_custom_field

create_custom_field('Task' {
    "fieldname": 'values',
    "label": 'Values',
    "fieldtype": 'Table',
    "options": 'Child Table'
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
parent = frappe.get_doc('Sales Order', 'SO-00002')
parent.append("items", {
    'company': 'company_name',
    'item_code': 'item_code',
    'item_name': 'item_name'
})
parent.save()
frappe.db.commit()
```